# Connect from GKE to Cloud SQL through private IP

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to connect from a pod in GKE to Google Cloud SQL.

Last weekend I make it work, but when I deleted the pod and recreated it was not working and I am not sure why.

**Description**

I have a `nodejs` application that it is dockerized. It uses the library `sequelize` and connects to `postgres` database.

Sequelize is reading the variables from the environment and in kubenetes I pass them through a secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myapi-secret
  namespace: development
type: Opaque
data:
  MYAPI_DATABASE_CLIENT: XXX
  MYAPI_DATABASE_PORT : XXX
  MYAPI_DATABASE_HOST: XXX
  MYAPI_DATABASE_NAME : XXX
  MYAPI_DATABASE_USERNAME: XXX
  MYAPI_DATABASE_PASSWORD: XXX
```

And my pod definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapi
  namespace: development
  labels:
    env: dev
    app: myapi
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapi
      image: gcr.io/companydev/myapi
      envFrom:
        - secretRef:
          name: myapi-secret
      
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
          name: myapi
```

When I deploy the pod I get a connection error to the database

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied tcp://podprivateip:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1300:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1365:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1462:5)
    at Function.listen (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/app.js:46:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1344:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: 'tcp://podprivateip:3000',
  port: -1
}
```

I couldn't realize what I am missing

---

Thanks to @kurtisvg I was able to realize that I was not passing the host and port through env variables to express. However I still have a connection error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT postgresinternalip:5432

It is strange because the postgres (cloud sql) and the cluster (gke) are in the same gcp network, but it is like the pod can't see the database.

If I run a docker-compose in my local this connection is working.

Comment: Make sure If you are connecting from GKE, you must be running GKE 1.8 or higher on a VPC-native cluster. [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/private-ip#application_environment_requirements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're connecting over private IP, but the port you've specified appears to be `3000`. Typically Cloud SQL listens on the default port for the database engine:

- MySQL - 3306
- Postgres - 5432
- SQL Server - 1433

Comment: thanks for the answer, maybe I am making a mistake there I will double check. the ip and the port are from the container in the pod. I’ve passed the postgres port as a env variable in the secrets.

Comment: thanks for your answer I realized one of my mistakes was that I was not passing the right host to express. However I still can't connect to Cloud SQL. I will update the question. thanks

Comment: For the record, the initial problem was not the connection to the database, it was that I was not passing the right host/port to express. Then the problem was that I created a network in GCP, and I didn’t realize that when I changed the network in the database instance, that change never happened, so I have my cluster and my sql in different networks. Your answer guide me in the right way, thanks. Then I will try to use sql proxy as you suggested in the youtube video.